# git: redo an old commit only

Tags: git, revert

I've a project under git where the last commit has correct changes, but the next-to-last commit must be completely reverted, so the applied changes from the third-to-last to next-to-last must be "ignored".

The last commit and the next-to-last commit has no modified files in common.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to change history (delete an older commit) or just create a new commit that undoes an earlier commit? The latter can be done with `git revert`.

Comment: I prefer to create a new commit, in case the reversion causes some weird problem, I can always be able to see the older code changes.

Comment: @Peregring-lk Yes, this is the very purpose of `revert` : you keep your history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typical way to do this is

```
git revert HEAD^
# HEAD points to the last commit, so HEAD^ is the commit just before
```

It will create a new commit on top of the branch tip, containing the reverse changes that your faulty commit contains.

Note : this does not rewrite your history, no need to `--force` anything when you'll need to push.

Answer (score 4):

If you are in a branch you could use [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).

That is:

- Create a new branch from the last *good commit* (e.g: master)
- Then cherry-pick the last commit: `git cherry-pick <last-commit-sha>`